# Google Place search with more than one place name android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Hello, I want to search place based on latitude, longitude, radius and name of that place.

I have tried the code below:

```
HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?"));
request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
request.getUrl().put("name", "Pacific Beach");
request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
```

I have passed here San Diego's latitude and longitude and I am successfully getting Pacific Beach Location.

Now I want to get more than one name from api places for example
Now if I write above code with following changes:

```
      request.getUrl().put("name","Pacific Beach|Gaslamp|Ocen Beach|Uptown|Hilcrest|Mission Valley|Fashion Valley|North Park");
```

Here I am getting "not any location".

Can any one tell me how should I write above code.

I do not know if I want to multiple search result I have to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can specify multiple possibilities for the name.

One thing to try might be to add multiple `name` parameters, by indicating that they are an array (`name[]`). Might not work at all though, I haven't tested it.

Otherwise, you would probably have to get all the potential results, and then filter through them after you receive them.

Comment: manavo i have tried in "types" like  ""sublocality|sublocality_level_4|sublocality_level_5|" it is working on that but not on places

Comment: Yep, the documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) does say that in types that works, but it doesn't say that it does in names. I'm afraid you'll probably have to get all the results without specifying the name, and then narrowing down the results locally.